# How do you run a R script which was written using older version of packages and R in latest R version and packages?

Tags: r, shiny, version, shinydashboard, shiny-server

I have a R script for shiny app. I don't know which versions of packages or R was used while writing that script. Now I have to run that script. It's causing a lot of errors due to version issues. Is there any short cut with which I can run that script without errors?

Comment: Nope. A script file doesn't contain any information about package versions. How to move forward really depends on exactly what kind of errors you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using package **checkpoint** to install packages from the date on which the script last worked. If your packages were up to date with the latest versions at that time, you will have a reproducible environment.

```
# current repository
getOption("repos")
#                        CRAN 
# "https://cran.rstudio.com/" 
# attr(,"RStudio")
# [1] TRUE

# current library
.libPaths()
# [1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library"

# current package version
packageVersion("dplyr")
# [1] ‘1.0.5’

library(checkpoint)
# the script ran successfully on 2019-01-01
checkpoint("2019-01-01")
# Can I create directory ~/.checkpoint for internal checkpoint use?
# ...
```

A new library will be created populated with packages from the checkpoint date.

```
getOption("repos")
# [1] "https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2019-01-01"
.libPaths()
# [1] "/Users/csjcampbell/.checkpoint/2019-01-01/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/3.6.2"
# [2] "/Users/csjcampbell/.checkpoint/R-3.6.2"                                       
# [3] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library"

# packages are installed as versioned on the snapshot date
packageVersion("dplyr")
# [1] ‘0.7.8’
```